# Custom view page for unformatted list

Tags: 10, views

I have a view (*Values_culture*) and I set up the *views-view-unformatted--values_culture.html.twig* file as template for that view. In my case, the template is not detected, or the template does not print values.

In the attached screen the format type is *Grid*. Please ignore that.

How can I properly customize the view templates and print each item from the specific content type mentioned in the view?

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you enabled Twig debugging? The debug output will show you the correct template name.

Comment: Yes, I already enabled this. Anyway, now it is identifying the template and getting the outputs. thanks.